# A better way to combine two Linq Queries into one in MVC5 Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

in my MVC Application using EntityFramework I have a self referencing table: customers with `customerParentID`. For children with no emails I want to be able to channel correspondence to parents Email.  This is the solution I have that works but I am hitting database 3 times and I want to combine the last 2 into one.

**Controller  Linq Query**

`useParentEmail` is a bool which is true for children with no Email
`Id` is obtained by a parameter

```
var b = db.Lists.SingleOrDefault(a => a.LatestTxnId == Id);
 var customerWithNoEmail = db.Customers.SingleOrDefault(a => a.CustomerID == b.CustomerID && a.useParentEmail);
    if (customerWithNoEmail != null)
      {
      var customerParent = db.Customers.SingleOrDefault(a => a.CustomerID == customerWithNoEmail.ParentCustomerID);
         customerParentEmail = customerParent.Email;
       }
```

This query hits database twice is there a  better way I can do this to hit database once?  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you use Entity Framework or Linq to SQL or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Entity Framework with the correct navigation properties in the model so that joins work automagically, something like this could work (I've used [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) and linq to objects for ease of example). To be honest although I used to be a heavy user of Entity Framework I haven't used it for a few years so I could be a little rusty.

```
 var customers = new[]
 {
    new { CustomerID = 1, useParentEmail = true, email = "", ParentCustomerID = (int?)2 },
    new { CustomerID = 2, useParentEmail = false, email = "parent@example.org", ParentCustomerID = (int?)null },
    new { CustomerID = 3, useParentEmail = false, email = "child@example.org", ParentCustomerID = (int?)null }

 };


int id = 1;


var emails = (from c in customers
            join p in customers on c.ParentCustomerID equals p.CustomerID into childrenParents
            from cp in childrenParents.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where c.CustomerID == id
            select new
            {
                c.CustomerID,
                email = c.useParentEmail == true ? cp.email : c.email
            }).SingleOrDefault();


emails.Dump();
```